# IF Condition in PL/SQL Function fails to return

Tags: plsql

I have this function for some test purposes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(in_offset number) return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
BEGIN

if in_offset is null then

  RETURN q'{
   SELECT 'no offset' FROM dual
  }';
else
  RETURN q'{
   SELECT 'offset set' FROM dual
  }';
end if;
END;
```

If i call it like

select * from test(5);
select * from test(1);

it keeps returning no offset as a result.
Is conditional return possible at all and if so why is this not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected for me:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (in_offset NUMBER)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     IF in_offset IS NULL
  6     THEN
  7        RETURN q'{
  8     SELECT 'no offset' FROM dual
  9    }';
 10     ELSE
 11        RETURN q'{
 12     SELECT 'offset set' FROM dual
 13    }';
 14     END IF;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM f_test (5);

'OFFSETSET
----------
offset set

SQL> SELECT * FROM f_test (null);

'NOOFFSET
---------
no offset
```

This is

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL>
```

Comment: interesting. in my case it is Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0.. I have dropped it and tried again still the same..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any 19c database to try it so - I believe what you say, but can't help much.